# Numerical solution of 2D nonlinear equation

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I try to solve the following equation:
$$u_t = (u^2 u_x)_x + (u^2 u_y)_y$$
$$0\le x\le10,   0\le y\le 10$$
Originally, my initial conditions are: $u(0,x,y) = 0$ ewerywhere except of circle $(x-5)^2 + (y-5)^2 = 1$ where $u = 5$ and any simple boundary conditions. I think it can be difficult to write such conditions and I wanted to try with one-point source $u(0,x,y)$ = 0 everywhere except of one point $u(0,5,5) = 5$.
But, at first I wanted to write the simplies one: $u(0,x,y) = 1$ everywhere.
So, I tryed to code it, but it doesn't work. Can you help me to write it right?

```
tt = 5.;

s = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
     u[t, x, y]*u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + 
      2*u[t, x, y]*(D[u[t, x, y], x])^2 + 
      u[t, x, y]*u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + 
      2 u[t, x, y]*(D[u[t, x, y], y])^2;
    u [0, x, y] == 1,
    u[t, 0, 0] == 0, u[t, 0, 10] == 0}, u[t, 10, 0] = 0, 
   u[t, 10, 10] = 0,
   u, {t, 0, tt}, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}];


Table[Plot3D[Evaluate[u[t, x, y] /. First[%]], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> False], {t, 1, 5}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not claim this to be a complete answer.

There were some syntax issues in your code. Even after correct them there were issues about the boundary conditions. Note that boundary conditions should be specified along an edge of the boundary. So u[t, 0, 10] == 0 won't work as at a specified time the condition is specified for a specific point and not an edge. The following works:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], t] == 
   u[t, x, y]*u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + 
    2*u[t, x, y]*(D[u[t, x, y], x])^2 + 
    u[t, x, y]*u[t, x, y]*D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + 
    2 u[t, x, y]*(D[u[t, x, y], y])^2,
  u[0, x, y] == 1, u[t, x, 1] == 0, u[t, 1, y] == 0, u[t, 10, y] == 0,
   u[t, x, 10] == 0}, u, {t, 0, tt}, {x, 1, 10}, {y, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: But code gives a mistake:"InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {2,0.000101111,0.000101111} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used."

Comment: Also, how should I code one-point source in the canter of my plane?

Comment: I tryed to write: `T[x_, y_] := 5 /; (y == 5) && (x == 5)
T[x_, y_] := 1 /; (y != 5) && (x != 5)` before NDSolve and added in Do[ ] cicle the following: `u[0,x,y] = T[t_,x_,y_]`. But I just obtained a lot of mistakes

Comment: It works fine for me. Which version are you on ? I am on version 11.0.0. I am not sure how to code one point source.

Comment: I use version 11.1. It's strange

Comment: @DavidJohnson Apart from `NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.`, the answer by Lotus works fine for me.

Comment: Yeap, I have found my mistake. Thank you. Now I'm trying to write one-point source.